# Automate MIN and MAX temperatures for a certain date

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table, worksheet-function, array-formulas

I have big amount of data (60k rows) in Excel that is similar to this:

```
Temperature Humidity    Date
20.1        68      22-dec-14
20.3        67      22-dec-14
20.4        65      22-dec-14
20.0        64      23-dec-14
20.5        64      23-dec-14
20.9        65      24-dec-14
21.4        64      24-dec-14
23.4        64      25-dec-14
23.8        65      25-dec-14
23.9        64      25-dec-14
18.4        64      25-dec-14
```

I created new columns outside this table that contains the individual dates and I want to extract the MAX, MIN and possibly the AVERAGE of that date

```
DATE      MIN   MAX  AVG
22/Dez/14
23/Dez/14
24/Dez/14
25/Dez/14
```

I tried but I can't seem to find a way for Excel to work for me. Could you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you try a PivotTable:

[image: SO33296377 example]

Comment: Yes this is a good alternative, plus one. Pivot tables are a powerful reporting tool.

Comment: This is the simplest for my level. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose column A contains the dates, and column B the values. I've allowed 6 rows in each; extend as necessary.

Consider a sample date in $D$1. The formulas you need are:

1. MIN: `=MIN(IF(D1=A1:A6,B1:B6,MAX(B1:B6)))`. (You need to enter this as an *array* formula).
2. MAX: `=MAX(IF(D1=A1:A6,B1:B6,MIN(B1:B6)))`. (You need to enter this as an *array* formula).
3. Use `AVERAGEIF` out of the box.

Remember that you need to press Ctrl + Shift + Return to enter an *array* formula. Then it's a simple case of copying that formula downwards.

They return the minimum or maximum value of the entire sample if a given date is not present in the set, which might not be desirable. You could adjust this behaviour with a containing `IF`.

Comment: I wouldn't want to *assume* that Temperature was at $A$1 ;-)

Comment: Yes it would appear to be an extra column. Unless the OP has used some extremely funky formatting... Seriously though, this is quite an advanced requirement, and the spreadsheet will be intricate. If the OP cannot adapt this solution then they should consider the pivot table approach.

Comment: Indeed it isn't, Bathsheba, but I could move it around. I tested your formulas and it works. Thanks!

Comment: It's also worth noting that the pivot table solution will be faster. My formulas will not be quick in their execution.

Answer (score 1):

You can take care of the pseudo-MIN/MAX with the [AGGREGATE¹ function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) using the **14** ([LARGE](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/large-function-3688ad91-0b0c-43db-8ef8-825a5e5871db)) and **15** ([SMALL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SMALL-function-4050a82e-659a-4ef6-a970-c963a6f69c29)) sub-functions together with the **6** (*ignore errors*) option and the [AVERAGEIF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIF-function-ff3c70f9-5afe-4d3e-87d4-717187f98c20) can take care of the rest.

[image: MINIF, MAXIF, AVERAGEIF]

The standard formulas in F2:H2 are,

```
=AGGREGATE(15, 6, ($A$2:$A$60000)/($C$2:$C$60000=$E2), 1)
=AGGREGATE(14, 6, ($A$2:$A$60000)/($C$2:$C$60000=$E2), 1)
=AVERAGEIF($C$2:$C$60000, $E2, $A$2:$A$60000)
```

Fill down as necessary. An advantage of this method is that you can get the second, third, etc smallest or largest simply by raising the **1** (*k ordinal*) number at the right end of the AGGREGATE formula.

---

¹ <sub>The [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) was introduced with Excel 2010. It is not available in earlier versions.</sub>

Comment: This was surprisingly fast on my 60K entries table, but the pivots are simpler for me to manipulate. Thanks!